# How do I install Ubuntu with encrypted root, home, and swap partitions?

Tags: installation, partitioning, 12.10, encryption

I would like to install Ubuntu 12.10 with two features:

- partitioning of my disks (`/` and `/home` should be separated, plus eventually a swap partition)
- encryption of those partitions

How should I do that in the Ubuntu 12.10 installer? I know I should choose the option "Something else" at the step called "Allocate drive space". But what should I do after that?

Answer (score 2):

Ideally that setup would have /boot on another media along with the keyfiles in an encrypted partition. Very similar to this: http://wiki.ubuntu.org.cn/UbuntuHelp:FeistyLUKSTwoFormFactor

This is something I have been trying to make work on 12.04 LTS, which if finished would nicely solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this turns out to be a mistake, at least for me.

But perhaps it happened to you also. I thought I was downloading 12.10 from the simple button on the ubuntu.com site, now that there is only one download to be used.

However, what I got was the 11.10 installer. Maybe there was a moment when a particular mirror wasn't up to date. This needless to say would not include the encrypt option.

Now I have 12.10, and it offers encryption and the LVM - fine.  You can look at the link above for my correction and any details -- good fortune, Jorge.